# Exotic GROUP BY In MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

Consider a typical GROUP BY statement in SQL: you have a table like

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     1 |
| B    |     2 |
| A    |     3 |
| B    |     4 |
+------+-------+
```

And you ask for

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Value) as Value
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

You'll receive

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     4 |
| B    |     6 |
+------+-------+
```

In your head, you can imagine that SQL generates an intermediate sorted table like

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     1 |
| A    |     3 |
| B    |     2 |
| B    |     4 |
+------+-------+
```

and then aggregates together successive rows: the "Value" column has been given an aggregator (in this case SUM), so it's easy to aggregate. The "Name" column has been given no aggregator, and thus uses what you might call the "trivial partial aggregator": given two things that are the same (e.g. A and A), it aggregates them into a single copy of one of the inputs (in this case A). Given any other input it doesn't know what to do and is forced to begin aggregating anew (this time with the "Name" column equal to B).

I want to do a more exotic kind of aggregation. My table looks like

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     1 |
| BC   |     2 |
| AY   |     3 |
| AZ   |     4 |
| B    |     5 |
| BCR  |     6 |
+------+-------+
```

And the intended output is

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     8 |
| B    |    13 |
+------+-------+
```

Where does this come from? A and B are the "minimal prefixes" for this set of names: they occur in the data set and every Name has exactly one of them as a prefix. I want to aggregate data by grouping rows together when their Names have the same minimal prefix (and add the Values, of course).

In the toy grouping model from before, the intermediate sorted table would be

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     1 |
| AY   |     3 |
| AZ   |     4 |
| B    |     5 |
| BC   |     2 |
| BCR  |     6 |
+------+-------+
```

Instead of using the "trivial partial aggregator" for Names, we would use one that can aggregate X and Y together iff X is a prefix of Y; in that case it returns X. So the first three rows would be aggregated together into a row with (Name, Value) = (A, 8), then the aggregator would see that A and B couldn't be aggregated and would move on to a new "block" of rows to aggregate.

The tricky thing is that the value we're grouping by is "non-local": if A were not a name in the dataset, then AY and AZ would each be a minimal prefix. It turns out that the AY and AZ rows are aggregated into the same row in the final output, but you couldn't know that just by looking at them in isolation.

Miraculously, in my use case the minimal prefix of a string can be determined without reference to anything else in the dataset. (Imagine that each of my names is one of the strings "hello", "world", and "bar", followed by any number of z's. I want to group all of the Names with the same "base" word together.)

As I see it I have two options:

1) The simple option: compute the prefix for each row and group by that value directly. Unfortunately I have an index on the Name, and computing the minimal prefix (whose length depends on the Name itself) prevents me from using that index. This forces a full table scan, which is prohibitively slow.

2) The complicated option: somehow convince MySQL to use the "partial prefix aggregator" for Name. This runs into the "non-locality" problem above, but that's fine as long as we scan the table according to my index on Name, since then every minimal prefix will be encountered before any of the other strings it is a prefix of; we would never try to aggregate AY and AZ together if A were in the dataset.

In a declarative programming language #2 would be rather easy: extract rows one at a time, in alphabetical order, keeping track of the current prefix. If your new row's Name has that as a prefix, it goes in the bucket you're currently using. Otherwise, start a new bucket with that as your prefix. In MySQL I am lost as to how to do it. Note that the set of minimal prefixes is not known beforehand.

Comment: Is the full table scan slow?  Are you sure it is not doing that?

Comment: What about `GROUP BY LEFT(name, 1)`?

Comment: The full table scan *is* slow; I can tell because when I ask to EXPLAIN the query it says it is using a filesort.

Comment: GROUP BY LEFT(name, 1) might work in this setting but in general the length of the minimal prefixes is not known.

Comment: (And in general it isn't the same for different prefixes.)

Comment: What's the algorithm for deducing the minimal prefix(es)?

Comment: To find the minimal prefix of a given name, you take the shortest prefix that is an English word. (This is somewhat obfuscated from my use case, but in the same spirit.) To find all of them you could select only those names that are themselves words.

Comment: So:  A, AN, BAD but not B?  Wait!  You picked B??  Please change your use case to follow the rules _and_ to show what happens in edge cases.

Comment: It happens that my use case has the special property (not present in my worked example) that every minimal prefix is an English word, which is what allows the "local" determination of minimal prefixes. If you want you can pretend that I use a version of English where "B" is a word :) .

Comment: So, what's the set of minimal prefix(es) for  ( CAB, CAD, CHOP ) ?  or ( DAD, DADDY, DUD ) ?  Let's limit it to English words here.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me. In your scenario the minimal prefix sets are {CAB, CAD, CHOP} and {DAD, DUD}. Note that these had to be determined "globally". *In my use case*, which is different from the example given to demonstrate the concept, I can determine the prefixes locally because of the English word property, but that's *not* part of the definition. It simply provides a possible alternate strategy for the query.

Comment: So an algorithm is to remove all words for which there is a prefix already in the list.  (Or maybe that is what you said, but it did not sink in.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2**

It occurred to me that if the table is ordered by `Name`, this would be a lot easier (and faster). Since I don't know if your data is sorted, I've included a sort in this query, but if the data is sorted, you can strip out `(SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Name) t1` and just use `FROM table1`

```
SELECT prefix, SUM(`Value`)
FROM (SELECT Name, Value, @prefix:=IF(Name NOT LIKE CONCAT(@prefix, '_%'), Name, @prefix) AS prefix
      FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Name) t1
      JOIN (SELECT @prefix := '~') p
      ) t2
GROUP BY prefix
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ad96a/16)

**Edit**

Having slept on the problem, I realised that there is no need to do the `IN`, it's enough to just have a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause on the JOINed table:

```
SELECT t1.Name, SUM(t2.Value) AS `Value`
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.Name LIKE CONCAT(t1.Name, '%')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table1 t3
                  WHERE t1.Name LIKE CONCAT(t3.Name, '_%')
                  )
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Updated Explain (`Name` changed to `UNIQUE` key from `PRIMARY`)

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref             rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY             t1      index   Name            Name        11          NULL            6       Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY             t2      ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL            6       Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  t3      index   NULL            Name        11          NULL            6       Using where; Using index
```

Updated [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdf51/10)

**Original Answer**

Here is one way you could do it. First, you need to find all the unique prefixes in your table. You can do that by looking for all values of `Name` where it does not look like another value of `Name` with other characters on the end. This can be done with this query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table1 t2
                  WHERE t1.Name LIKE CONCAT(t2.Name, '_%')
                  )
```

For your sample data, that will give

```
Name
A
B
```

Now you can sum all the values where the Name starts with one of those prefixes. Note we change the `LIKE` pattern in this query so that it also matches the prefix, otherwise we wouldn't count the values for `A` and `B` in your example:

```
SELECT t1.Name, SUM(t2.Value) AS `Value`
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.Name LIKE CONCAT(t1.Name, '%')
WHERE t1.Name IN (SELECT Name
                  FROM table1 t3
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                    FROM table1 t4
                                    WHERE t3.Name LIKE CONCAT(t4.Name, '_%')
                                    )
                  )
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Output:

```
Name    Value
A       8
B       13
```

An `EXPLAIN` says that both of these queries use the index on `Name`, so should be reasonably efficient. Here is the result of the explain on my MySQL 5.6 server:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref             rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY             t1      index   PRIMARY         PRIMARY     11          NULL            6       Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY             t3      eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     11          test.t1.Name    1       Using where; Using index
1   PRIMARY             t2      ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL            6       Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  t4      index   NULL            PRIMARY     11          NULL            6       Using where; Using index
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdf51/1)

Comment: Instead of a regexp, use `LIKE` patterns, because MySQL optimizes them better. `RLIKE CONCAT(t1.Name, '.*')` is `LIKE CONCAT(t1.name, '%')`, `RLIKE CONCAT(t4.Name, '.+')` is `LIKE CONCAT(t4.name, '_%')`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks - a good point. I started with an RLIKE because I had something more complicated, but should have simplified. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Small point of note, your body text still refers to regex  though they are gone from the query

Comment: 1. In my system EXPLAIN doesn't show I'm using any indexes at all.

2. A priori shouldn't this be really slow? You are basically doing O(n^2) work just to find the prefixes, and then if there are k prefixes you do an additional O(nk) work to aggregate the data for them.

Comment: @citizen My system definitely shows that indexes are being used. In answer to your second point, which is correct, I've edited the post with a significantly simplified query so as to combine some of the steps. Note that I was simply trying to answer the implicit "can this be done in MySQL" part of the question.

Comment: @citizen I've added another option which is **much** simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints on how to do the task.  This locates any prefixes that are useful.  That's not what you asked for, but the flow of the query and the usage of `@variables`, plus the need for 2 (actually 3) levels of nesting, might help you.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT `Prev`
    FROM  
        (
        SELECT  @prev := @next AS 'Prev',
                @next := IF(LEFT(city, LENGTH(@prev)) = @prev, @next, city) AS 'Next'
            FROM ( SELECT  @next := ' ' ) AS init
            JOIN ( SELECT  DISTINCT city FROM  us ) AS dedup
            ORDER BY  city
        ) x
    WHERE  `Prev` = `Next` ;
```

Partial output:

```
+----------------+
| Prev           |
+----------------+
| Alamo          |
| Allen          |
| Altamont       |
| Ames           |
| Amherst        |
| Anderson       |
| Arlington      |
| Arroyo         |
| Auburn         |
| Austin         |
| Avon           |
| Baker          |
```

Check the `Al%` cities:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT city FROM us WHERE city LIKE 'Al%' ORDER BY city;
+-------------------+
| city              |
+-------------------+
| Alabaster         |
| Alameda           |
| Alamo             | <--
| Alamogordo        | <--
| Alamosa           |
| Albany            |
| Albemarle         |
...
| Alhambra          |
| Alice             |
| Aliquippa         |
| Aliso Viejo       |
| Allen             | <--
| Allen Park        | <--
| Allentown         | <--
| Alliance          |
| Allouez           |
| Alma              |
| Aloha             |
| Alondra Park      |
| Alpena            |
| Alpharetta        |
| Alpine            |
| Alsip             |
| Altadena          |
| Altamont          | <--
| Altamonte Springs | <--
| Alton             |
| Altoona           |
| Altus             |
| Alvin             |
+-------------------+
40 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```